# Nhibernate Set how to intercept Add() method

Tags: nhibernate, intercept

I need a solution for this: How to intercept ISet.Add method so I don't need to do children.Parent=parent, but jus parent.Children.Add(children);

```
public class MyClass
{
public MyClass Parent;
public ISet<MyClass> Childrens;
}
```

I want to do this:

```
var mc = new MyClass();
var mc2 = new MyClass();
mc.Childrens.Add(mc2);
```

and not

```
var mc = new MyClass();
var mc2 = new MyClass();
mc.Childrens.Add(mc2);
mc2.Parent=mc;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply create an `AddChild` method which does that.

You could also expose the public property as readonly collection as Frederik demonstrates...

[What is the best practice for readonly lists in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645918/what-is-the-best-practice-for-readonly-lists-in-nhibernate/646824#646824)

Comment: Yes I can do that but this will use a number of people, and I can't hide ISet.Add() method and some will use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IList<MyClass> Childrens
```

Comment: why IList<T> instead of ISet<T>?